# Fix 'AddThis' plugin 'more layer' floating

Tags: javascript, html, css, addthis

I have implemented [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com) plugin in my website, however, when I resize the browser's width and before it hits the `@meduim` screen style the `more` layer get displayed in a wrong floating position.

[image]

I snapped this `css` from their `out of the box` implementation

```
element.style 
{
   z-index: 1000000;
   position: absolute;
   visibility: visible;
   top: 681px;
   left: 753px;
   display: none;
}

#at15s.atm 
{
   background: none!important;
   padding: 0!important;
   width: 160px!important;
}
```

I do reference this `js` [file](http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-53ca654f25fce060) provided by them, and it takes care of the css I guess. What `css` should I share with you guys to get familiar with this problem so you may give me suggestions for the floating problem?

Comment: Do you have this on a page I could see?  I'm not sure why it's happening, it should re-position the menu to the left.

Comment: Yes, please check this http://www.outcomes.somee.com/stories/tyler-yarde.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and i added this little css to my page and now the `more`-layer opens up to the left instead to the right.
You should then try to reset these style´s in your media queries for smaller screens.

```
#at15s.atm {
    left:auto !important;
    right:0 !important;
}
```